# Ruby Array Intersection Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, intersection

I've been attempting to intersect an array using the "&" interesection method with the Twitter API in Ruby. I've tried it several different ways and it simply says... "undefined method `&' for Twitter...". It does the same for "|" and "-". All documentation I've read says you simply need to use the "&" to intersect the arrays and get a new array with the values of the same values. I'm very new to Ruby, what am I missing?...

```
@var = @array1 & @array2
```

My controller code is below:

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base

   def index
      redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => params[:id]
   end

   def show
      begin
        @users = $client.user_timeline(params[:id])[0..9] #Gets last 10 tweets
        @userinfo = $client.user(params[:id])
        @friends = $client.friend_ids(@userinfo.id)
      rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound
          redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => '404'
      end
  end

  def compare
      @users = $client.user_timeline(params[:id])[0..0] #Limits Timeline request to 1
      @users2 = $client.user_timeline(params[:id2])[0..0] #Limits Timeline request to 1
      @userinfo = $client.user(params[:id])
      @userinfo2 = $client.user(params[:id2])

      @friendlists = $client.friend_ids(@userinfo.id) #Variable 1
      @friendlists2 = $client.friend_ids(@userinfo2.id) #Variable 2
  end

end
```

My View code is...

```
<% @friendmerge = @friendlists & @friendlists2 %> #<--This should work right?

<% if !@friendmerge.blank? %>
   <pre><%= JSON.pretty_generate(@friendmerge) %></pre>
   <% else %>
   This didn't work.
<% end %>
```

I'm new to Ruby, so please be kind. I fully realize I may be struggling with a few core principles. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can u print out what does friendslist look like?

Comment: If your error message says "undefined method \`&' for Twitter...", then you have a `Twitter` object, not an `Array`.

Comment: sawa. Thanks for the answer. When I convert it to an object, it will print as an array(Thank you!)...however, when I try the intersect, the @friendmerge variable is blank and doesn't print. I know there are ~200 intersecting items with the users I am comparing, so it should print...unless I'm missing something else.

Comment: have you checked the friendlists and friendlists2 variable data type?. I guess it's not an array.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects do not support (array) intersection they might still know how to convert into an array that does. You could try

```
@friendmerge = @friendlists.to_a & @friendlists2.to_a
```

in order to find out.